# Getting mutual friends MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, algorithm, mongoose, graph

Follower: A person who is following the current user

Following: A person who is followed by the current user

I have a model named friends which are basically followers of one another.
Now I want to find mutual persons whom both of the users follow.

One way is to get 'followings' of the second user and then get 'followings' of the first user where 'to' in 'list of following' of second.

But this doesn't seem good.

I am therefore looking for an aggregate type of thing.

Schema:

```
const schema = new Schema({

    from:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref:'User'
    },

    to:{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref:'User'
    }

});
```

if **a** (from) : **b** (to)
and a (from) : c(to)
and **a** (from) : **d** (to)
and **b** (from) : **d** (to)

I want **'d'**